# Laravel, trying to make a count with values from database

Tags: laravel

I need some help with Laravel, I'm trying to do a list, with information from my database, with a count, for example: 
[List image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaIT2.png)

How can I make to count how many times the same place appears in my list? Remembering: My place list comes from my DB, the place can variable. I can't make it count. Here is my code:

```
<table border=`1px` class="table-teste">
    <tr>
        <td><h3> Place</h3></td>
        <td><h3> Count</h3></td>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($setor_data as $setor)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$setor->setor}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

And my Controller:

```
  $setor_data = DB::table('atividades')
      ->where('local', $condominio)
      ->whereDate('date', '>=', $dtinicio)
      ->whereDate('date','<=',$dtok)
      ->orderBy("setor")
      ->select('setor')
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

User groupBy to count each item in list in the query, like following:

```
$setor_data = DB::table('atividades')
               ->where('local', $condominio)
               ->whereDate('date', '>=', $dtinicio)
               ->whereDate('date','<=',$dtok)
               ->orderBy("setor")
               ->select('setor', , DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
               ->get();
```

Then in the blade view:

```
@foreach ($setor_data as $setor)
   <tr>
      <td>{{$setor->setor}}</td>
      <td>{{$setor->total}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope, it helps...

Comment: MAN, YOU'RE MY HERO IT WORKED PERFECTLY FINE, AWESOMEEEEEE, THANK YOU SO MUCH, YOU SAVED MY LIFE, APPRECIATE, THANK YOU SO MUCH NAZEM, LOVE YOU